# How to solve foreclose problem in start up my application?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application,I want to my application automatically invoked,when I switch on my device.so i used  this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in my application's manifest.xml file and i used service , activity and register Broadcast receiver in manifest.xml file.but I got foreclose error appear in when will i start up my device.How solve this proplem.
My Receiver code given bellow
 context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ServicesDemo.class));
//In my mainfest.xml for myReceiver

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  
 </intent-filter> </receiver>
```

I got this exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.servicedemo.MyReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: @thanks cxOder,I posted logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am developing an android application,I want to my application automatically invoked,when I switch on my device

Users generally hate that with the fiery passion of a thousand suns. Please make this configurable and disabled by default.

Also, bear in mind that if too many developers abuse this, the core Android team is likely to prevent you from starting an activity at boot time.

> How solve this proplem

Do what the error message told you to do: add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to your `Intent`.